# kmllayer remove function is not working in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kml

I am trying to remove the KML layer from the map using kmlLayer.removerLayerFromMap() but it's not working

when I add KML layer on the map I am storing it in ArrayList of KMLLayer
and whenever user press remover kml layer button I remove all kmllayer from the map on onClickListener of the button

`adding kmlLayer`

```
KmlLayer kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(mMap, new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr),
                        getContext());
if(!kmlLayer.isLayerOnMap()){
                    Log.i("LAYER","LAYER added");
                    kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();
                   downloadedKMLFiles.add(kmlLayer)
                }
```

`Removing kml layer`

```
  @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Remove","Remove KML");
            if(!downloadedKMLFiles.isEmpty()){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < downloadedKMLFiles.size(); i++){
            KmlLayer kmlLayer = downloadedKMLFiles.get(i);

            if(kmlLayer.isLayerOnMap()){
                if(kmlLayer.getMap() !=  null){
                    Log.i("LAYER","LAYER PRESENT");
                    kmlLayer.removeLayerFromMap();
                }
            }else {
                Log.i("LAYER","LAYER ABSent");

            }
        }
    }
        }
    });
```